# PHPMailer, error at form domain with minus

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem with PHPMailer..
I sent mail with:

```
$mail->SetFrom('cipcirip@cipcirip.com', 'cip-cirip');
```

and I give mail on gmail
and I send mail with:

```
$mail->SetFrom('cipcirip@cip-cirip.com', 'cip-cirip');
```

and I don't give the mail...
the real adress is cipcirip@cip-cirip.com

Comment: No error messages, $mail->send() return true

Answer (score 0):

I think phpmailer doesn't care and the problem is in the MTA. It is possible that it refuses to send from anywhere but cipcirip.com if that's your domain name.